# Responsive twitter bootstrap carousel with multiple elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a twitter bootstrap carousel with 3 items on a row. The example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/at606jpe/). How I can make it responsive? I want to display one single element for the mobile devices.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">  
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/CCCCCC&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

And

```
.carousel-inner .active.left  { left: -33%;             }
.carousel-inner .active.right { left: 33%;              }
.carousel-inner .next         { left: 33%               }
.carousel-inner .prev         { left: -33%              }
.carousel-control.left        { background-image: none; }
.carousel-control.right       { background-image: none; }
.carousel-inner .item         { background: white;      }
```

And

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length>0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-responsive-carousel might be useful

Comment: @Anil - It's not becasue it has only 1 item for desktop not 3 as I said.

Comment: 1 item for both I.e desktop n mobile?

Comment: I guess you downvoted OP? If you'd see the revised answer, i guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @paulalexandru Check my answer. Hope i will help. Remember to refresh the browser each time you change the width for testing !

Comment: @Anil - no! 3 items for desktop, 1 item for mobile. Check the question

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. Change `col-xs-4` to `col-md-4`.

Then change javascript code to

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 10000
})
if($( window ).width() >= 768){
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
  else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
}
```

When the browser width is greater than or equal to 768px, then it will show three images in a row. When width is less than 768px, then only 1 image is shown.

[Link to my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdbhzkxn/)

**IN MOBILE DEVICES**

[image]

**IN DESKTOP**

[image]

**NOTE : Refresh your browser after changing width each times.**

Hope it will help

Comment: This answer's output is bascially my exact initial answer's.. which is not what OP was looking for.

Comment: @Tarekis I have edited the javascript also. Please look

Comment: I was talking about output not code, i didn't accuse you of plagiarism, but that your answer is not what OP wants, i misinterpreted it initially too. Also it has display issues, like my inital answer too, the items display underneath each other.

Comment: He likes to show 3 items in a row in desktop. and 1 item in mobile.. But your code doesn't satisfy what he is looking for.

Comment: Yeah i am aware of that, and yes it now does. Resize the result page, you'll see. Also, change to #6 on your example in mobile, you'll see what i meant is not working.

Comment: i don't get u. I checked your answer fiddle, But i don't get the correct output.Have only 1 image in both mobile and desktop

Comment: That's impossible, either you have a **tiny** screen or you just don't resize. At bootstrap's `md` width three items are displayed.

Comment: Dino your answer has 2 issues. First is that you should refresh the page whenever you change the width, but you know that mobile and tables can change their width from landscape to portrait when turning them arownd, so if they do that, it won't work. The second point is that this works when you convert from 3 items to 1, but in case you want to convert from 3 to 2 what will happend ? Or in case you want 4 elements on xs, 3 elements on md, 2 elements on sm and 1 element on xs? I made a basic example, but what I actually need to implement is something more complex.

Answer (score -2):

See the Bootstrap [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) documentation, there you will find the rules you need to solve your problem.

You change the first `column`'s class to `col-xs-12 col-md-4` or something similar and the other `column`'s class to `hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4`.

The `col-xs-12` will display items with 100% on a very small screen and as soon you enter a medium screen the `col-md-4` will make an item take 33.3..% of it's row's width. The `hidden-xs` and `hidden-sm` will prevent the items to be displayed on `xs` and `sm` screens.

You change your Markup to:

```
<div class="item active">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
        <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
      </div>    
    </div>
```

and remove this CSS:

```
.carousel-inner .active.left  { left: -33%;             }
.carousel-inner .active.right { left: 33%;              }
.carousel-inner .next         { left: 33%               }
.carousel-inner .prev         { left: -33%              }
```

also your Javascript copies your elements, but as you need different classes on the columns you'll need to alter it if you need it.

**EDIT:**
Think i just figured out what you actually want to do, sorry about misinterpreting before.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/zzw2e3su/)